# While play audio from phone via bluetooth, I need to keep windows (system tray) media play on top of other windows

Tags: laptop, audio, bluetooth, windows-media-player, phone

I play music through my pc from my phone via bluetooth.  I am looking for a setting to keep the windows media player on top of all windows.  I am also looking to control player with media keys or ahk script.

Also, is there a specific name for this player as it is not the same theme of windows media player.

Answer (score 0):

The [Windows Media Player Plus!](http://bmproductions.fixnum.org/wmpplus/) plug-in adds global hotkey functionality to WMP. It also allows you to configure a hotkey for bringing WMP to the front of all other windows.

Comment: I'm actually looking to control a remote media player that appears in my system tray when I connect my phone's music and audio via bluetooth.   I'm not sure if it is rooted in WMP or not.  Are you familiar with this player?

Answer (score 0):

The program in the below image is the program I am looking to control.

I'm not familiar with the actual name.

Its a remote player for my phone media.  Do you know the actual name?

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with that player but it certainly looks like it's using WMP under the covers. If you launch WMP while something is playing in the remote player, is WMP showing the same song being played? Or can you play something different in WMP and the remote player at the same time?